# Update Labels Arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I used UpdateLayer(df, update_layer, source_layer, ) function to update my maps to a given standard set of .lyrs I saved in a separate folder. Is there a way to do this with labels as well? Here is the script I use to update layer symbology of my map from another map's symbology settings, though I only show to update_township() function as it gets repetitive.

```
#arcGIS_exchange_question.py

import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
print('this is the df: ', df)
source_path = "D:\\Symbology"
print('this is the source path: ', source_path)
updateLyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,'', df)
print('this is the updateLyrs list: ', updateLyrs)

def update_townships(df, updateLyr, source_path):

    sourceLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(source_path + "\\" + "Township.lyr")
    print("This is the source layer: ", sourceLyr)
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLyr, sourceLyr, True)
    print("Done Updating: ", updateLyr)

print("Now to update: ", len(updateLyrs))
for updateLyr in updateLyrs:
    print("Looking to update symobology of layer: ", updateLyr)
    if updateLyr.name.find('Township') != -1:
        print("Updating Township")
        update_townships(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Section') != -1:
        update_sections(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Index') != -1:
        update_index(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Lot') != -1:
        update_lots(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Block') != -1:
        update_blocks(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Parcel') != -1:
        update_parcels(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Water') != -1:
        update_water(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Road') != -1:
        update_roads(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    elif updateLyr.name.find('Subdivision') != -1:
        update_subdivisions(df, updateLyr, source_path)
        continue

    else:
        print("Could not find a source layer update the {} symbology with".format(updateLyr))
print("All Done")
```

Basically I am wondering if there is an arcpy function that can set a layer's label parameters to a another layer's label parameters. I did see in an ArcGIS pro video that arcpy.mapping is much less flexible than arcpy.map (ArcGIS's Pro's library) when it comes to labels, so I realized I may need to jump to ArcGIS pro to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: UpdateLayer is a function (not a module): https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm

Comment: arcpy.mapping.layer.labelClasses http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/LabelClass/00s30000002t000000/ is read/write via a list of LabelClass objects

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question with a bit more detail about the labels you have and what you're trying to change them to?  Your code doesn't seem to mention labels at all - have you tried using [LabelClass](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/labelclass-class.htm)?

Comment: correct this is an example of the code I used to change symbology.  I want to do the same thing but with labels.  I am wondering if there is a function that does something similar to arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer() but with labels.  I want layer properties from one map, to be used on another.

Comment: @Mwspencer have you tried using [LabelClass](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/labelclass-class.htm)?

Comment: This may work, I need to test it, as the documentation does not dive as deep into the tool as I am hoping to go.